# Is there an Oberon-2 compiler for Windows that supports the XYplane module?

Tags: oberon

I'm currently using Oxford Oberon-2 compiler but it doesn't seem to support the XYplane module, which makes it kind of difficult to follow the examples from Wirth's book about the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you need type-bound procedures, you could try OBNC which implements Niklaus Wirth's revision of the original Oberon language:

https://www.miasap.se/obnc/

https://www.miasap.se/obnc/oberon-report.html

See also

http://people.inf.ethz.ch/wirth/Oberon/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this project: https://github.com/rochus-keller/Oberon

It includes an IDE with source-level debugger and semantic navigation and supports most of Oberon-2 (and Oberon-07 or 90) and also the XYplane module which is part of the Oakwood libraries.

Here is the pre-compiled version for Windows: http://software.rochus-keller.ch/OberonIDE_win32.zip. Just unpack and run, no installation necessary.

The generated assemblies run on all platforms where Mono is available, and the IDE runs on all platforms, where Qt5 is available.

There are also a platform independent FFI (foreign function interface) which supports e.g. the SDL2 library (which is also used in the XYplane module), and other useful language extensions, see http://oberon-lang.ch.